# Grunt + Protractor + CucumberJs

Tags: protractor, cucumberjs, grunt-plugins

I'm trying to use Grunt for my Protractor+Cucumber tests, I was using grunt-protractor-runner plugin, but I realized that it was not running my `After` steps, therefore my test fails.

Which plugin do you recommend? I was trying to use `grunt-protractor-cucumber` and I can't make it work!

Can you please assist?

Answer (score 0):

We use [protractor cucumber framework](https://www.npmjs.com/package/protractor-cucumber-framework) and it's been great.

With it you can do things like:

```
this.After({tags: ['@myCustomScenarioTag']}, function() {
    //do stuff after a specific scenario has run
});
```